# Input special keystroke on powershell

Tags: powershell

Am just new to powershell and I wrote a script to keystroke anything entered on the script below to an active notepad window.

However, everything went fine except if special characters (`~%!@#^&*()` etc) are contained in that text. Is there is anyway to fix this?

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('notepad')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('text to Keystorke')
```

After lot of search I found a VBS that can handle this. I am confused on how to convert this to a powershell so I can include it on my single script file?

any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

```
sString  = "Text to keystroke is here"
sStringToSend = ""
For ii = 1 To Len( sString)
  sChar = Mid( sString, ii, 1)
  Select Case sChar
  Case "{", "}", "(", ")", "[", "]", "^", "%", "+", "~"
    sStringToSend = sStringToSend & "{" & sChar & "}"
  Case Else
    sStringToSend = sStringToSend & sChar
  End Select
Next
objShell.SendKeys sStringToSend
Wscript.Sleep 300

discardScript()    
'
Function discardScript()
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strScript = Wscript.ScriptFullName
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strScript)
End Function
```

Comment: The characters `+^%` are used for passing shift, ctrl and alt modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB script check each character to see if its a special character, if it is then it wraps it in curly braces `{}`.

You could reimplement this in PowerShell by doing the same steps. Loop over each character, test if its a special character, escape the character by wrapping in curly braces if true, then build a new string by appending the output.

I used a match regex where `|` is the `or` operator and `\` to escape regex special characters rather than a `switch` statement with a case for each special character

```
$Text = [char[]]'example{}()[]^%+~'
$FormattedCharArray = foreach ($char in $Text) {
    if ($char -match '({|}|\(|\)|\[|\]|\^|%|\+|~)'){
        "{$char}"
    } else {
        $char
    }
}
$FormattedCharArray -join ''
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! i edited your script a little so it can fix inside my full script.

Comment: @shadad Glad it worked. Here's a [guide on what to do if an answer works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for you.

Comment: BenH, sorry i couldn't up vote your answer but mark it as accepted answer. sorry for being late :D. regards.